# How to upgrade windows service using PowerShell Desired State Configuration

Tags: powershell, service, dsc

Below is an example of my config, install works fine but if I replace '\\BuildMachine\Output\MyService.exe' with a newer version DSC fails with file in use errors. What is the correct way to upgrade a windows service using DSC? Thanks.

```
Configuration ServiceTestConfiguration {
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName xPSDesiredStateConfiguration

    Node localhost
    {
        File EnsureLatestServiceExist {
            Ensure = 'Present'
            Type = 'File'
            Checksum = 'ModifiedDate'
            SourcePath = '\\BuildMachine\Output\MyService.exe'
            DestinationPath = 'c:\MyService\MyService.exe'
        }

        xService EnsureServiceStarted {
            Ensure = 'Present'
            DependsOn = '[File]EnsureLatestServiceExist'
            Name = 'MyService'
            DisplayName = 'My Service'
            Description = 'My Service'
            Path = 'c:\MyService\MyService.exe'
            StartupType = 'Automatic'
            State = 'Running'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that you can do this with the built in resources.  I started writing a DSC solution about 6 months ago and after a little tinkering with the built in stuff opted to create a custom resource to deploy our services.  This allowed me to write completely custom logic that met our needs allowing for the comparison of binaries and configurations.  I think you should consider going down this road.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/authoringresource

Answer (score 2):

I have not found a built-in method to accomplish this, but the Script resource lets you pretty much do anything.

Add a Script resource that checks to see if the remote (source) file was updated. If the remote file was updated, stop the service. Make the File resource depend upon the Script resource so that it runs before the file copy. The Service resource will run last and start the service again.

```
Script StopServiceCheck
{
    SetScript = 
    {
        Stop-Service -Name ServiceName -Force
    }
    TestScript = 
    {
        $LocalFile = "C:\Path\To\Local.exe"
        $RemoteFile = "\\Path\To\Remote.exe"

        #Returns false if the remote file is newer than the local file or use -eq
        return ((Get-Item -Path $RemoteFile).LastWriteTime -le (Get-Item -Path $LocalFile).LastWriteTime) 
    }
    GetScript = 
    {
        $LocalFile = "C:\Path\To\Local.exe"
        $RemoteFile = "\\Path\To\Remote.exe"
        $return = @{Result = "Executables match"}

        If ((Get-Item -Path $RemoteFile).LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Item -Path $LocalFile).LastWriteTime) { $return.Result = "Remote file is newer" }

        return $return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Open source PowerShell module Carbon has custom DSC Resource for this very purpose: http://get-carbon.org/Carbon_Service.html

Comment: But this doesn't address the 'file in use' issue when upgrading to a new exe. Isn't that the problem being asked here?

Answer (score 0):

It's not one desired state, it's two desired states.

The first desired state is: *The service is properly shut down and ready for maintenance*.

The second desired state is: *The service is active and running using the latest version of the code*.

Write it as two scripts.

Comment: This goes against everything I've learned about desired state, you don't say step one, step two, etc...  Now this suggestion is the exact opposite, it's saying I have one desired state that is dependent on another happening first.

Comment: @AaronStainback DSC is a configuration management tool that you're using to deploy software. In the context of a deployment, it's two states. If you were using DSC simply to enforce correct configuration, then yes, you'd just have a single script to enforce that configuration. But your deployment requires an "offline" state.

Comment: Sorry but I just disagree, saying I must run one configuration before another in order or else things break defeats the primary purpose of DSC.  The promise of DSC is to push a config and make it so no matter the current state of the system.  I should not need to know anything about the current state of the system.  I am working on a custom resource that will stop the service on file changes, this should accomplish what I am looking for.

Comment: You have all ready broken up this desired state into 2 resource in your example.  You really need to write a custom resource to do what you want  in one step..  I really think that is the way forward for you.