# DSC: How to stop and start a windows service

Tags: ms-release-management, dsc

I want to do a very simple thing with DSC (Desired State Configuration):

Stop a windows service, deploy files and finally start the service again. Thus I had the following:

```
Service ServicesStop
{
    Name = "TheTestService"
    State = "Stopped"
}

File CopyDeploymentBits
{  
  Ensure = "Present"
  Type = "Directory"
  Recurse = $true
  SourcePath = $applicationPath
  DestinationPath = $deployOutputPath
}

Service ServicesStart
{
    Name = "TheTestService"
    StartupType = "Automatic"
    State = "Running"
}
```

But unfortunately this is not working as it is not allowed to have the same name (***Name = "TheTestService"***) in a configuration twice (Why? In this case it would totally make sense) as a workaround I tried something like this

```
Configuration MyTestConfig {
    Node $env:COMPUTERNAME {
        Service ServicesStop
        {
            Name = "TheTestService"
            State = "Stopped"
        }

        File CopyDeploymentBits
        {  
          Ensure = "Present"
          Type = "Directory"
          Recurse = $true
          SourcePath = $applicationPath
          DestinationPath = $deployOutputPath
        }
    }
}

Configuration MyTestConfig2 {
    Node $env:COMPUTERNAME {
        Service ServicesStart
        {
            Name = "TheTestService"
            StartupType = "Automatic"
            State = "Running"
        }
    }
}

MyTestConfig
MyTestConfig2
```

Looks insane - but it works!

Unfortunately, I am not using plain DSC I am using it with Microsoft Release Management and here, it seems that the **'MyTestConfig2' is not executed anymore** (or something else goes wrong that is not mentioned in the logs).

How can I realize this simple scenario with dsc within the context of release management? Or is there even a better way to do something like this?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302781/how-to-upgrade-windows-service-using-powershell-desired-state-configuration

Comment: That is bad news! Perhaps it is than better to use Chef. I think to remember that it works well with their solution. But thanks a lot for your input and the link (If the link ever gets broken, the 'solution' seems to be: Write your own custom DSC resource).

Comment: @DanielMann - perhaps you would like to post an answer that I can accept? You pointed me to the right direction. :)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to create a service resource that takes both Name and State as key. Feel free to extend this simple service resource (*I will try to get to it when I find time*) https://github.com/nanalakshmanan/nServiceManager

Comment: Thanks for your input. Looks very good. After Daniel Mann's post I came up with the reduced solution I just posted so I would love to give the credits to him but your answer is at least an up vote! :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Afer Daniel Mann's post I came up with this minimal solution:

```
[DscResource()]
class InstallStopCopyStartServiceResource {
    [DscProperty(Key)]
    [string]$ServiceName

    [DscProperty(Mandatory)]
    [string] $SourcePath

    [DscProperty(Mandatory)]
    [string] $DestinationPath

    [void] Set()
    {
        $needsInstallation = $false;

        $testService = Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $this.ServiceName}
        if ($testService -eq $null) 
        {
            $needsInstallation = $true;
        } elseif ($testService.Status -eq "Running") 
        {
            Stop-Service $this.ServiceName
        } 

        # Due to stupid Copy-Item behavior we first delete all old files
        # (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/20b9d259-90d9-4e51-a125-c0f3dafb498c/copyitem-not-overwriting-exising-files-but-creating-additional-subfolder?forum=winserverpowershell)
        Remove-Item -Path $this.DestinationPath -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

        # Copy files
        Copy-Item -Path $this.SourcePath -Destination $this.DestinationPath -Recurse -Force

        if ($needsInstallation -eq $true) 
        {
            # Install service
            $param = 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installUtil ' + $this.DestinationPath  + '\service.exe'
            Invoke-Expression $param
        }

        # Start the service
        Start-Service $this.ServiceName

        # Configure service
        Set-Service $this.ServiceName -StartupType "Automatic"
    }

    [bool] Test()
    {
        # Always perform all steps
        return $false
    }

    [InstallStopCopyStartServiceResource] Get()
    {
        return $this
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

At least for me the following works best:

```
# Configure the Service 1st
Service Servicewuauserv {
    Name = 'wuauserv'
    BuiltInAccount = 'LocalSystem'
    State = 'Running'
}
```

And then:

```
# Ensure it is running
ServiceSet wuauserv {
     Name = 'wuauserv'
     BuiltInAccount = 'LocalSystem'
     State = 'Running'
}
```

Yep, makes it more complex, but the split seems to work best with some services.